# Modify the code to replace digit with characters from a different column from the CSV uploaded

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have been working on modifying the below logic in such a way that if the value of the column extracted below : l[5] is a digit and it is something like _58982, it will simply replace it with the value of the next column which is l[6] in the CSV file and the final output will become : LEARNING_MAT.

Below is the sample logic but it is not working as expected.

```
       for l in self.lines[1:]:
        try:
        if(re.match(r'_[\d]{19}', l[5])):
            print("Processing Line No : {}")
            s = Sample(verified=True,
                    count=l[1],
                    intent=l[6].replace(':','_').replace('-', '_'),
                    token_tree=TokenTree(l[8]),
                    protected=self.protected)
            else:
                  s = Sample(verified=True,
                    count=l[1],
                    intent=l[5].replace(':','_').replace('-', '_'),
                    token_tree=TokenTree(l[8]),
                    protected=self.protected)

        except Exception as ex:
            raise ValueError("Bad sample definition: %s (check tabs)" % l)
        else:
            print("Processing 5 No : {}")
            ret.append(s)
```

Comment: It is insufficient to just say it is not working as expected. Please edit your question to include more detail including the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: If input is : _581 , i.e a digit, it should pick from the next column which has characters, hence the logic inside try is written like that but as per current scenario, it is not able to detect any digits or the regex is failing and it's going directly to the else block.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your code is doing because the indentation is messed-up. Please [edit] it and correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for this -

```
if(re.match(r'_[\d]{19}', l[5])):
                unaccented_string = unidecode(l[6])
                # surpassing all control characters, symbols and punctuations
                res = "".join(char for char in unaccented_string if category(char)[0] not in ["C", "S", "P"])
                #remove duplicate spaces
                res = " ".join(res.split())
                append_str = "X_"
                if(res[:1].isdigit()):
                    res = append_str+res
                s = Sample(verified=True,
                        count=l[1],
                        intent=str(res).replace(':','_').replace('-', '_').upper().replace(" ","_"),
                        token_tree=TokenTree(l[8]),
                        protected=self.protected)
                ret.append(s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).